# foundation 5 with compass and nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation

I am just getting started with nodejs and I'm trying to understand how everything works...and I'm getting trouble. Please forgive me in advance for the number of questions and the confusion it could generate.

What I'd like to set up is a nodejs server using express, mongodb, passeport, jade, foundation5 with sass and compass, socketio and html boilerplate.It seems to me as a "regular" project but for some reason I couldn't find any skeleton or generator like the one's yeoman provide for it. Is there a key problem with this architecture ?

If I got it correctly, compass is a set of tools for sass but if you go to the [foundation website](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html). Either you can install compass with foundation or either grunt with foundation and sass but not foundation with compass and grunt.
Is there a logic behind that ?

Another solution is to compile the sass files on the nodejs server like this:

```
   var express = require('express'),
   compass = require('node-compass'),
   path = require('path'),
   app = express();

   app.configure(function() {
   app.use(compass());
   app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
   });

   app.listen(3000);
```

On which cases is it better to compile it on the server using a middleware such as compass or node-sass rather than using a grunt command that generate the client plain css file to be deployed ?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

I misunderstood one thing:

> libsass, the C version of the popular stylesheet preprocessor, Sass.
> It allows you to natively compile .scss files to css at incredible speed
>
> At the time of writing libsass (and therefore Node-sass and therefore grunt-sass) does not support Compass.

[source](http://benfrain.com/lightning-fast-sass-compiling-with-libsass-node-sass-and-grunt-sass/)

It explains why you can rather use libsass or compass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grunt command is more effective method, if you have a lot of visitors, better for you is to compile all style into css by grunt command

Middleware is more flexibility, you can change your styles on the fly, but for each user request, all styles will compile again and again. so your server will work more slowly

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You do mean that doing it on the server allow me to create some new sass script on the fly using javascript ?
I can't see any good practice where you would have to do this kind of things.

Comment: No, i mean, you can change scss, and server compile this scss to css, when user request these styles. When you use grunt command, you change scss, compile scss to css with grunt and upload to the server. To be honest I can't see any good practice to use middleware too, only for faster prototype.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's exactly my point, I don't see any use of this. Plus it breaks even more the separation between the server side and the client side (which is anyways broke as soon as you use jade). Plus, I disagree with the argument to say it is faster to prototype since you can use grunt 'watch files' which will do exactly the same.
Note: I do understand the point in using jade with express "on the server" side and not only use grunt to compile the html. Since you can "send" argument from the server that will change the "jade" page but I don't see the point with sass.

Comment: Putting your answer as accepted as there was no better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using grunt with compass. Don't forget to install the *grunt-contrib-compass* nodes module!

`npm install grunt-contrib-compass --save-dev`

Here's my gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    compass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          specify: 'library/scss/style.scss',
          outputStyle: 'compressed',
          sassDir: 'library/scss',
          cssDir: 'library/css'
        },
      }
    },

    watch: {
      // grunt: { files: ['Gruntfile.js'] },

      css: {
        // files: '**/*.scss',
        files: 'library/scss/style.scss',
        tasks: ['compass']
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```